# Arduino analogReference() switching during run time

Tags: arduino, adc

I'm trying to read ADC value off two sensors one that uses 5V as VREF and one that uses the INTERNAL  2.54V as VREF so I use analogReference(); between the reading and it seems to affect the measured values even after a 10mS delay after each analogReference(); Is there a way to use it properly with the code or do you have to choose a single reference in the setup() and that's it?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the reference voltage will affect the ADC readings until the internal ADC capacitor has charged/discharged. Depending on how long that takes to charge/discharge is how long it will take until you can get accurate readings. I would try increasing the delay time more and see if that helps, or see how many readings you have to take before it stabilizes. Here's a link to Arduinos analogReference() page.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/

Comment: Yeah they say something similar here "Notes and Warnings
After changing the analog reference, the first few readings from analogRead() may not be accurate."

But then how do you calculate how many reading \ time it take to discharge it? if a read is initiated how does it discharge the ADC capacitor?

Answer (score 0):

following up on bunker answer --- run one dummy conversion, to consume that residual charge.

By the way, I'd make this a COMMENT, but stackX does not allow my browser to comment.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, please use the comment system

Comment: If you are having trouble commenting, it may make sense to normalize your browser configuration by removing any userscripts or similar that prevent commenting, or raise an issue on meta if there is a real bug. It seems that comments work for almost every 50+ rep user on this site.